# Why did Sulu go back to the job?

Tags: plot-explanation, tumhari-sulu

From the movie "Tumhari Sulu", I had a doubt regarding the climax. Sulu teary-eyed-ly quit the RJ job owing to the fact that she felt she did not do justice to her family responsibilities.

Next scene she asks Maria for a job as the food supplier to the radio station. Which she and her husband take up. All cool till there.

But in the final scene she goes back into her RJ job along with handling the food supply with husband. My question is, why did she go back to the job ? it was still a late night job and nothing changed or was shown as changed in the scenes between her quitting and going back. (like husband realizing her passion or her better handling or something of that sort)

So were any scenes deleted between or did I miss something ? Why did Sulu go back to the same job if nothing changed for her ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What did change is, her husband started this *tiffin* supply from home and had more time to spend on their son. Her husband didn't stop her from making her dream come true and she also helped him getting new work so it all worked out pretty well for all of them. It was not clearly said but that's what happened.

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumhari_Sulu) summaries the plot very accurate too:

> Next day police find her son and bring him home. Sulu goes to her office and resigns. She feels that she is not able to handle the emotional turmoil at home. Just as she is leaving, she finds the receptionist having a fight with the tiffin service guy. Sulu has an idea and she requests Maria to give her the contract for the tiffin service. Next, we see Ashok managing the tiffin business and Sulu going to her job; managing both the household and her professional life in her own unique style.

Comment: + 1 i mean i expected this too.. but thats what it is.. a possible explanation. i was wondering if some scenes were cut or something.. this is shown in the movie ?

Comment: I am not sure if they cut any scene or not but we see Sulu asking fro tiffin service contract and in next scene we see both managing there jobs as yu said in question

Comment: ok I overlooked the fact that her husband can now work/manage from home meaning the kid has a monitor !

Comment: i actually read the wiki description too before posting but the situation did not seem to change from before "Ashok managing the tiffin business and Sulu going to her job" and "Ashok managing the clothes business and Sulu going to her job" both are the kind of the same situation .. your explanation is much better, thank you !

Comment: @Anu7 welcome .

Answer (score 1):

Sulu did her job nearly one month as an RJ, so family members are still adjusting to this new change, because of that all the things happened and went wrong. The final scene shows how they are managing everything well so that she can continue her job. She mentioned she really enjoyed as working an RJ, so it is an ideal job for her, which her husband might realise later and supported her to continue.